# ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'membership' at row 2

Tags: mysql

This is my table

```
mysql> describe clients;
+------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)                         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(50)                     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| membership | enum('Silver','Gold','Diamond') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| interest   | set('Movie','Music','Concert')  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I try

```
INSERT INTO clients (name, membership,interest) VALUES ('Pizda','Gold', 'Music'),('Kratez','Premium', 'Movie,Concert');
```

than I have problems

```
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'membership' at row 2
```

What does data truncated refer to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enum `membership | enum('Silver','Gold','Diamond')` does not have value `Premium`.

```
CREATE TABLE clients(
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   membership  enum('Silver','Gold','Diamond') 
);

INSERT INTO clients(membership)
VALUES('Premium');
-- Data truncated for column 'membership' at row 1

INSERT INTO clients(membership)
VALUES(NULL);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce6fffbc025fc8e2d535d4cc7ded0ff7)**

Comment: But it can not leave a  blank field?

Comment: @RichardRublev You could pass `NULL` directly